# Flow router Redirect On Data Insert Meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

Im using react , meteor and flow router. How do I redirect once data has been inserted to the database

This is the function I have

```
Meteor.call('insertQuestion', header, content,      
 usernameoremail,date,function(error){
  if(error) {
     show({text: error.reason, pos: 'bottom-left'});
  }
  else {
    show({text: "Your Question Has been posted", pos: 'top-right'}); 
  }
});
```

Which flow router function should I use?

Comment: you can use FlowRouter.go(page,params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FlowRouter.go(pathDef, params, queryParams);**

This will get the path via FlowRouter.path based on the arguments and re-route to that path.

You can call FlowRouter.go like this as well:

```
FlowRouter.go("/blog");
```

You can check more about flow-router [here](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#flowroutergopathdef-params-queryparams)

```
Meteor.call('insertQuestion', header, content,
 usernameoremail,date,function(error){
  if(error) {
    show({text: error.reason, pos: 'bottom-left'});
  }
  else {
    show({text: "Your Question Has been posted", pos: 'top-right'});
    FlowRouter.go(pathDef, params, queryParams)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FlowRouter.go("/path");` to redirect the user. You'll want to call this within the callback function, so that your code becomes:

```
Meteor.call('insertQuestion', header, content,
 usernameoremail,date,function(error){
  if(error) {
    show({text: error.reason, pos: 'bottom-left'});
  }
  else {
    show({text: "Your Question Has been posted", pos: 'top-right'});
    FlowRouter.go("/somewhere");
  }
});
```